# Отправка фото в телеграм бот из yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Привет не могу отправить фото в телеграм из yii2, при попытке отправки фото происходит токая ошибка `Too few arguments to function TelegramBot\Api\BotApi::sendPhoto(), 1 passed in D:\OpenServer\domains\univer.lc\controllers\TelegramController.php on line 27 and at least 2 expected`
Вот код

```
Yii::$app->bot->sendPhoto([
            'chat_id' => '-1001320591192',
            'photo' => Yii::getAlias('@app/web/images/hello.jpg'),
            'caption' => 'Найдите меня!'
        ]);
```

Comment: Что именно вам не ясно в том, что вам написано в ответе на ваши  действия ? sentPhoto ожидает как минимум второй параметр, вы передаете один.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В методе библиотеки (компонента Yii2), который вы используете ожидается как минимум 2 параметра. Почитайте внимательно документацию или посмотрите в исходном коде, какие параметры на вход ожидаются

**UPD:** если вы используете библиотеку `yii2-developer/telegram-bot`, то вызов этой функции будет таков

```
Yii::$app->bot->sendPhoto(-1001320591192, Yii::getAlias('@app/web/images/hello.jpg'), 'Найдите меня!');
```

Comment: Я использую расширение SonkoDmitry/yii2-telegram-bot-api

Comment: @sherozjuraev в данном случае библиотека `SonkoDmitry/yii2-telegram-bot-api` унаследована от `TelegramBot/Api` и имеет такое же API, как я описал выше